# PowerShell quotes for Start-Process ArgumentList

Tags: powershell, quotes

I'm trying to have the app [tablacus explorer](http://www.eonet.ne.jp/%7Egakana/tablacus/explorer_en.html) open a folder path. This works fine with the following formatting:

```
$exe = 'S:\Tools\explorer\TE64.exe'
Start-Process $exe -ArgumentList '"Tabs,Close other tabs" "Open,C:\Program Files"'
```

But I would really like to have the path in a variable (`$dir = 'C:\Program Files'`), and I can't seem to get the quotes right so it gets interpreted properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start-Process Variables In -ArgumentList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35117204/start-process-variables-in-argumentlist)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found two solutions for this on the [MS Blog](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/455837c4-44a5-4359-b179-02f6b6f4d95b/using-double-quotes-within-a-string?forum=winserverpowershell):

```
$Args = @"
"Tabs,Close other tabs" "Open,$dir"
"@
    
Start-Process $exe -ArgumentList $Args
```

or

```
Start-Process $exe -ArgumentList """Tabs,Close other tabs"" ""Open,$dir"""
```

Answer (score 0):

I found sometimes you need another level of quotes.

In my case, I have to set variables in `-Arguments /v`, so I had to use `\""` to do that.

```
Start-Process `
  -FilePath "Installer.exe" `
  -Arguments "/s /qn /v""SOME_PARAM1=\""STRING_IN_PARAM\"" SOME_PARAM2=\""STRING_IN_PARAM\"""
  -Wait ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your parameters are constant strings then create a shortcut and call that instead.

Set the 'target' of the shortcut to:

```
"S:\Tools\explorer\TE64.exe" "Tabs,Close other tabs" "Open,C:\Program Files"
```

Name your shortcut 'TE64' and call it in powershell like this:

```
start-process S:\Tools\explorer\TE64.lnk
```

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax works fine for me, try this:

```
-ArgumentList "\`"$($variable)\`""
```