# Start-Process Variables In -ArgumentList

Tags: windows, powershell

I was wondering if someone with more expertise could help me with a little problem I'm having with using Variables in `-ArgumentList` when using `Start-Process`.

If I run the Exe without using `Start-Process`

```
.\DeploymentServer.UI.CommandLine.exe register --estNumber $Number --postcode $PostCode --password $Password
```

everything works fine, the command runs and the software is registered.

If I try

```
Start-Process .\DeploymentServer.UI.CommandLine.exe -ArgumentList "register --estNumber $Number --postcode $PostCode --password $Password" -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

or

```
$Arguments = "register --estNumber $Number --postcode $PostCode --password $Password"
Start-Process .\DeploymentServer.UI.CommandLine.exe -ArgumentList $Arguments -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

the command runs but is unable to register, stating that it can not match the details provided. So I'm assuming the issue lies either in the passing of the arguments to `Start-Process`, or `-ArgumentList` interpreting the variables in the string. Am I missing something really simple here? Possibly to do with the `$` in the `-ArgumentList`?

Comment: What *are* the "details provided"? Does it help if you provide the argument list as an array?

Comment: the details held in the 3 variables "$number = 999999" "$postcode = a12 1ab" "$Password =password". There is nothing spectacular about any of them. They work fine when not using Start-Process

Comment: `Start-Process` never add quotes for you, while PowerShell normally try to be smart and add quotes, when arguments contains spaces: `$Text='With Space';start cmd "/c echo $Text" -NoNewWindow -Wait;cmd /c echo $Text`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have a space in your `$postcode`, so you need to put the argument in quotes:

```
Start-Process .\DeploymentServer.UI.CommandLine.exe -ArgumentList "register --estNumber $Number --postcode `"$PostCode`" --password $Password" -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try. Is there any reason you know why there would be a problem with only when using Start-Process? I'm hoping to try to understand why it might be interpreting it differently then running it "natively"

Comment: As @PetSerAl mentioned, PowerShell handles variables smartly when it runs statements itself. But here you pass an argument string to `Start-Process` where PowerShell only fills in the variables and `Start-Process` takes the string and runs the command.

Comment: "*You have a space in your $postcode*" What space is this referring to? I see no space in the variable name `$postcode`.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered several posts online saying to wrap a `Start-Process` `-ArgumentList` argument containing spaces in 2 layers of doubles quotes, escaping the inner double quotes with a back tick `, but at least in the context I needed it, that didn't work.  I found a conceptually similar solution which did work, however, i.e. a set of single quotes on the outside and a "traditional" backslash escape sequence on inner double quotes. I was guided to using this approach per this PowerShell issue post:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576

This example works for me (running a PS `Start-Process` command from `cmd.exe`):

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\Test.exe' -ArgumentList 'arg1','\"arg 2 w spaces\"','arg3'
```