# Providing local variable to Invoke-Command using $using:Variablename

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to perform unattended SQL Installation using configuration file and I'm using $Using:Password to pass the variable from local machine to the invoke-command but it seems that it is not taking the credentials.

When I remove the /SQLSVCPASSWORD then it works fine.

Anything I'm missing here?

```
$SQLNodes = @("SQL10")
Foreach ($node in $SQLNodes ) {
  $Password = "Verystrongpassword"
  if (Test-Connection $node -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    $Invoke = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $node {
      $Exe = 'C:\SQLServerFull\Setup.exe'
      Start-Process -FilePath $Exe -ArgumentList /ConfigurationFile="C:\Script\ConfigurationFile.INI", /SQLSVCPASSWORD=$($using:Password) -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput C:\error.txt
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the error

```
SQL Server 2017 transmits information about your installation  experience, as
well as other usage and performance data, to  Microsoft to help improve the
product. To learn more about SQL  Server 2017 data processing and privacy
controls, please see the Privacy Statement.

The following error occurred:
The SQL Server service account login or password is not valid. Use SQL Server
Configuration Manager to update the service account.
    
    Error result: -2061893563
    Result facility code: 1306
    Result error code: 69
```

Comment: This might be a quoting issue. Try using an [array of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30524456/503046) instead.